# Pick a random item from an array and pass it to a hidden field in gravity forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity, gravityforms

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_6', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_6', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_6', 'populate_posts' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_6', 'populate_posts' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {
    
    $metavalue = $_POST["input_4"];//store the value of the dropdown.
 
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
 
        if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'member',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'assets',
            'value' => $metavalue,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'         
        ))
          
           
        );

 
        //create array based on selection
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
 
        $choices = array();
 
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
        }
 
        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Select a Post';
        $field->choices = $choices;
 
    }
 
    return $form;
}
```

Hi guys,

The purpose of this code is to select from a dropdown which corresponds to a Custom Field, based on the selection, it will then generate a query which based on the metavalue and then put the posts in an array. I was able to store them in an array but I wish to pass a random value from that array to another hidden field in the same form. Is there a more efficient way of doing this particular code?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at Gravity Forms Populate Anything:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/

It will allow you to populate the posts in a Drop Down:

[image]

...and then populate data based on the selected item in other fields on the form.